SXA build error with latest version of node
Getting below error with node version 23.3.
PS C:\Source\eKeystoneHelix\KAO\FrontEnd\Themes\KAO\SupplierCentral\SupplierCentralNew> sxa build All
  #  Developer PowerShell Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.11.35431.28[3556]: void __cdecl node::fs::InternalModuleStat(const class v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<class v8::Value> &) at c:\ws\src\node_file.cc:1045
  #  Assertion failed: (args.Length()) >= (2)

----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 00007FF77EB3199B node::SetCppgcReference+15707
 2: 00007FF77EA999B1 DSA_meth_get_flags+89505
 3: 00007FF77EA845F8 DSA_meth_get_flags+2536
 4: 00007FF71F78F686

----- JavaScript stack trace -----

1: C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:34535
2: C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:34176
3: C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:34506
4: C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:173374
5: C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:173420
6: C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:173521
7: C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:258942
8: C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:261569
9: e (C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:262673)
10: get (C:\Users\kxpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore\sxa-cli\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:262740)

